# How to convert an object type

Tags: typescript, types

I want to determine the type from an object using the typescript magic. The original object looks like:

```
const ROUTES_CONFIG = {
    ONE: {
        path: '/',
        routes: {
            TWO: {
                path: '/two',
            },
            THREE: {
                path: '/three',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

I want to get the type corresponding to the object:

```
const ROUTES = {
    ONE: {
        TWO: {},
        THREE: {},
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's difficult to tell what you are asking. Do you just want the [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)?

Comment: Do you want to convert the above object into the second one?

Comment: You should get a simplified type. With fewer children.

Answer (score 0):

```
type ROUTES = typeof ROUTES_CONFIG;
```

Comment: You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)